# Correct use of class vs ID in table with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Bear in mind, I'm new to client-side scripting, learning my way through..

I need to create a page with tabular data and give user ability to click on specific link to bring modal popup and submit request.

I'm placing this form into DIV and show it using jQuery, no problem.
For the 'table' I have dilemma on how to hook up click and data best way. I tend to do it with classes, but then my HTML look this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <td class="tripId"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TripId")%></td>
    <td class="pickupDate"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PickupDate", "{0:MM/dd/yy}")%></td>
    <td class="from"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FromCity")%>, <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FromState")%></td>
    <td class="deliveryDate"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DeliveryDate", "{0:MM/dd/yy}")%></td>
    <td class="to"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ToCity")%>, <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ToState")%></td>
    <td class="weight"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Weight")%></td>
    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LoadedMiles")%></td>
    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RequiredEquipment")%></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="inquireLink"><strong>Inquire now</strong></a></td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

In javascript I hook to all hrefs like this:

```
// Hookup link events to handle modal popup
$(".inquireLink").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    inquireAboutTrip($(this));
});

function inquireAboutTrip($link) {
   // Link located on <TR> so we can traverse up and then into each cell to get data
}
```

So, I can traverse up to TR from link and than into each CLASS to find data inside TD. Then I can use this data on a form as I need. There is 2 problems: VS2012 complains about all those classes being undefined (of course they are not on CSS). Another problem is that for each row I have this repitition of markup.. I want it cleaner.
I understand that if I use jQuery I can rely on order of TDs inside TR. Code becomes more brittle but will be less HTML.

What is the common way to solve problem like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help here to step back and think about your structure a little bit, in terms of the data that it's holding.

What you have here is a row in a table, with a bunch of cells inside that row. One of those rows refers to the ID of some "Trip" entity. But really, all of the fields within that row refer to the same "Trip".

The way I generally solve this is to bring identifiers as high up in the hierarchy as makes sense. In this case, I'd identify the *row* using some sort of identification scheme (I usually make my own custom parameters, but you can use ID if you wish):

```
<tr tripId="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TripId")%>">
    <td class="tripId"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TripId")%></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="inquireLink"><strong>Inquire now</strong></a></td>
</tr>
```

Now, we can start to treat the `<tr/>` block as a whole "Trip":

```
$("[tripId]").each(
    function(indx, elem) {
        $(elem).find(".inquireLink").click( ... );
        // Or better yet, if there is only ever a single anchor tag in the "Inquire" cell:
        $(elem).find("a").click( ... );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, I wouldn't get too much heartburn from VS complaining about invalid classes. For all VS knows, they're coming from a CDN. Also, there's really no harm in an additional class hanging out not being used.

As far as brevity, you *could* use `<td>` order and drop the class attributes, but you'll lose the ability to restyle/reorder them later on without a code change (maybe you want to reorganize column order). I also wouldn't rely so much on finding the parent `<tr>`, but instead lean toward another class (like `.item`) so it's up to `.item` then down to `.to`, `from`, etc. This gives you the freedom to move to an `<ul>` or `<div>`s later on if you'd like.

Another option is to use `data-*` attributes, but, to me, that's another layer of bloat that's not necessary if the information is already there being presented and you're just re-skinning it. Unless the model was going to use AJAX and you're just storing a `data-id`, it's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for input, I will have to do some ajax on other pages and it will be useful

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the way it's meant to do now, that's exactly how classes are meant to be used. Ignore the warnings from VS, it isn't too good at validating HTML particularly when using ASP.NET templates funnily enough.

This method of specifying the class on each `<td>` is far superior to relying on the order of `<td>` in your jQuery in my opinion because your jQuery becomes so much more robust.

Your `tripId` could be on your `<tr>` though as then it is more readily available to your other `<td>`s. You will also be able to select your relevant data with `$('#trip-10 .weight')` for example.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr id="trip-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TripId")%>">
    <td class="tripId"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TripId")%></td>
    <td class="pickupDate"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PickupDate", "{0:MM/dd/yy}")%></td>
    <td class="from"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FromCity")%>, <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FromState")%></td>
    <td class="deliveryDate"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DeliveryDate", "{0:MM/dd/yy}")%></td>
    <td class="to"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ToCity")%>, <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ToState")%></td>
    <td class="weight"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Weight")%></td>
    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LoadedMiles")%></td>
    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RequiredEquipment")%></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="inquireLink"><strong>Inquire now</strong></a></td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks! It gives me some ideas. I pick Thomas's answer as it gives me another lesson/technique on how jQuery can be used